# Running task in background in PHP even after user logs out

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, background

I have done a website using php which basically does task of recording videos from a IP camera in the background. So here is what i do I login into my account and then hit a record button which calls the backend ajax script which executes a program and records videos successfully and stops as soon as i refresh or reload the page. Now what i want is the video recording script should continue in the background to record videos even after the user logout. how can i accomplish this task . Can anyone give me a simple idea to do this?

Have a look at my video recording code using ajax.
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145751/showing-a-loading-image-when-ajax-start-running-in-background)
Video recording is done by start.php which contains main logic.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP file starts another program right?

I assume in php you use something like popen or exec. Here is how you have it done without PHP waiting for it to finish:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

```
function execInBackground($cmd) {
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r")); 
    }
    else {
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");  
    }
}
```

Not sure what you mean by user logging out, if you mean log out from the website then it should not be a problem because PHP is no longer concerned with the recording program.

Comment: yes i do mean log out from website i want the process to execute in the background . 
how can i use the above function to run the file continuous ?

Comment: It is how you call the video capturing program. $cmd is the command you are using. This code goes in your php page.